# no longer able to provision to iPad2 after upgrade to iOS5

Tags: xcode, ios5, upgrade, provisioning

After upgrading to iOS 5.01, I can no longer provision to the device. I see the provisioning profiles on the device (via Organizer). And my xcode has the same developer cert that used to work just yesterday.

Anyone knows what could be the issue?

Comment: nevermind, i need to re-enable "use for development" again in organizer. upgrading resets that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to create one more time the certificated to add your device and profile, also, you can eliminate all the olders certificates to have only one.